# How to plot a time histogram of the ratio of _exists vs NOT _exists for a specific field in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, plot, histogram, kibana

Using kibana,
There's a way to filter the data for cases where a field exists, and there is a way to filter the data to get only requests where a field does NOT exist.

I'd like to plot a time histogram such that at each point I have a ratio of:
number of records where field X exists to the number of records where it doesn't exist.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a vertical bar chart. On the time axis you need to use a Date Histogram aggregation on a date field.

Then create a sub-aggregation (split series) and use a Filters sub-aggregation. You can then define two filters, one to filter documents for which the field exists, and another one for documents that do not contain the field. It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Works great, thank you so much!  Any way to make it a ratio though? or somehow see one as a relative percentage of the other instead of raw counts?